# Heroku inspect slug and list gems

Tags: heroku

How I can inspect the my Heroku app's slug? I'd like to see which versions of which gems it has installed.  I know when the slug compiles it lists which gems it installs, but I want to see what gems my app is using *now* (if it recompiles the gems differ, I am investigating a bug)

---

This is all the information I could find about my app, the gems aren't listed :(

```
$ heroku apps:info
=== placeboxy
Addons:        cron:daily
               pusher:sandbox
               shared-database:5mb

Database Size: 112k
Dynos:         1
Git URL:       
Owner Email:   
Repo Size:     1M
Slug Size:     6M
Stack:         bamboo-ree-1.8.7
Web URL:       
Workers:       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ heroku run gem list
$ heroku run bundle exec gem list
```

JD @ Heroku Support https://help.heroku.com/tickets/60850